# difference between kubectl get api-resources vs kubectl get crd

Tags: kubernetes

What is the difference between kubernetes api-resources and custom resource definitions (CRDs)?  The reason is the results returned (in terms of object list) *appears* to be similar but I don't see documentation on these.

Answer (score 0):

#### [Kubernetes Documentation — *Custom Resources*](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/api-extension/custom-resources/#custom-resources):

> Custom resources
>
> A resource is an endpoint in the Kubernetes API that stores a collection of API objects of a certain kind; for example, the built-in pods resource contains a collection of Pod objects.
>
> A custom resource is an extension of the Kubernetes API that is not necessarily available in a default Kubernetes installation. It represents a customization of a particular Kubernetes installation. However, many core Kubernetes functions are now built using custom resources, making Kubernetes more modular.
>
> Custom resources can appear and disappear in a running cluster through dynamic registration, and cluster admins can update custom resources independently of the cluster itself. Once a custom resource is installed, users can create and access its objects using kubectl, just as they do for built-in resources like Pods.

Comment: yes I did see that for custom (CRD).  Perhaps my question would be better expressed as an assertion: `Some api-resources are also custom resources, but some custom resources are not, just as some api-resources are native to kubernetes` - is this correct?  Just thinking in terms of a Venn diagram.